# How can i compare two string variable with Jekyll

Tags: string, variables, jekyll, contains

in Jekyll i have tow variable `{% assign a="/home/deep" %}` and `{% assign b="/home/deep/deeper" %}` now how can i check if b contains a ? My idea was `{% if b contains a %}` or `{% if b contains "{{ a }}" %}`
but both are always false....

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah of course. The only things i find is how to check if a variable contains a string like {% if a contains 'bla' %} but that is not why i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. After restart the hosting server it works.
For people with the same question:

```
{% if a contains b %}
```